# localStorage display stored image or default image

Tags: php, jquery

I am wanting to use `localStorage` to store the url path of the persons `gavatar`.

Here is the code I have been beating on... I think I am close, but just need help with getting this the next/last step.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
            if (localStorage.getItem("myAvatar") === null)
            {
                    <?php
                    $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower(trim('foo@foobar.com'))) . '?s=100&d=mm&r=g';
                    ?>
                    localStorage.setItem('myAvatar', '<?=$url;?>');
                    var myAvatar = '<?=$url;?>';
            }
            else
            {
                    var myAvatar = localStorage.getItem("myAvatar");
            }
    }
    else
    {
            var myAvatar = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?s=100&d=mm&r=g';
    }
    </script>
    <img id="avatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?s=100&d=mm&r=g">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('avatar').src = 'myAvatar';
    </script>
```

I know putting php inside of javascript is not good practices, so in addition to helping me solve this, I am very much open to hearing suggestions on a better way to approach the logic of acquiring the gravatar without having to ping gravatar if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the quotes when trying to set the source in the second script

```
document.getElementById('avatar').src = 'myAvatar';
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('avatar').src = myAvatar;
```

Otherwise you are just setting the source to be the string `'myAvatar'` rather than actually finding what the value of `myAvatar` is.

Just as a note, you could move all of the code in the first script tag to the second script tag, which would make it cleaner, and would give a better loading order.

Also, if you are just using the php code to format a string (i.e. not pulling it from a database), then you could just find out what it converts it to and hardcode it in. On the other hand, if you are planning to pull it from a database or non-static variable, it is fine this way, in my mind it is not bad practice to include php in this way.

Comment: Thanks Fred that got it working. And, good call with the update to using inverted expressions. Yeah, in this situation no DB calls as it only involves pinging gravatar.

Answer (score 1):

See this short doc:
http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/

read the comment in the source

```
<?php
function &get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
    $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
    $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
    $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";

    //* Change this to what you need if there's an image add else if needed */
    if ( $img ) {
        $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
        foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
        $url .= ' />';
        return $url;
    } else { 
        /** no image */
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?s=100&d=mm&r=g";
    }
}
//** make this happen */
$myAvatar =& get_gravatar(/** needs options read linked doc**/);
?>
```

Also you might want to read Example 3 from http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myAvatar = "<?php echo $myAvatar; ?>";
</script>
```